# docker-compose to Bluemix Failed. “TypeError: string indices must be integers”

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I am trying to this tutorial. Tutorial: [Creating a multi-container deployment with Docker Compose and IBM Bluemix Container Service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_ui.html#container_compose_intro)

However, an error occurred and I cannot understand what does it mean. Please tell me what is wrong.

Versions:

```
OS: macOS Sierra 
bx version 0.5.3+e1de255-2017-05-17T04:07:46+00:00
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

Environment Variables:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/{myname}/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/******
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
lets-chat:
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/hiroga/lets-chat
  ports:
   - "8080"
  links:
   - mongo
mongo:
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/hiroga/mongo
  expose:
   - "27017"
```

Error

```
$ docker-compose --verbose up
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml

~~~~~~~~~~

compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: lets-chat>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])

ERROR: for lets-chat  string indices must be integers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 116, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 876, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 416, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 66, in parallel_execute
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Any solution or hint is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there perhaps something earlier in the output that might hint as to the actual error?  (before the last string of `compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set([])` messages, maybe?)

Double check the image names (compare vs `bx ic images`, including the version if it isn't `latest`).

Other possibilities are - if the last messages above that aren't the feed_queue are dealing with `docker attach` or `docker start`, then the deploy may have actually been successful, but docker-compose is very optimistic in how long it defaults to waiting.  You can try bumping the timeout with `export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=300` or similar to give it a bit more patience to deal with remote servers.

If you check with `docker ps -a` and `docker-compose ps`, do those show if the actual containers got started?